# Cannot add permission_handler To pobspec.yami

Tags: flutter, dart

iam trying to add [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to my Flutter project ...

when i add it in `pobspec.yami` file it giving me this error :

```
    Because permission_handler >=8.2.0 depends on permission_handler_platform_interface ^3.7.0 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, permission_handler >=8.2.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
And because path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, permission_handler >=8.2.0 is incompatible with path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.
And because path_provider 1.6.28 depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1 and no versions of path_provider match >1.6.28 <2.0.0, permission_handler >=8.2.0 is incompatible with path_provider ^1.6.28.
So, because smart_bureau depends on both path_provider ^1.6.28 and permission_handler ^8.2.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because smart_bureau depends on both path_provider ^1.6.28 and permission_handler ^8.2.5, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

My Full `pobspec.yami` file :

```
name: smart_bureau

description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter_session: ^0.1.1
  provider: ^6.0.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1
  flutter_offline: ^2.0.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  settings_ui: ^1.0.0
  flutter_verification_code: ^1.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
  geolocator: ^6.2.1
  geocoding: ^1.0.5
  path_provider: ^1.6.28
  dio: ^4.0.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  dropdown_search: ^2.0.0
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/svg/
    - assets/img/
    - assets/ico/


  fonts:
    - family: Almarai-Regular
      fonts:
         - asset: assets/fonts/Almarai-Regular.ttf

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Note : i updated compileSdkVersion to 31 And i set

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

but didnot work alsso !

also note that i cannot update geolocator or geocoding to the newest version .. it giving me same error !

Answer (score 0):

upgrade the path_provider: ^2.0.6